# How to "Assert.That()" Items in a List match certain conditions with NUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, assert

I'm writing some unit-tests and want to check a result-list.

Here a simple example what i'm doing:

```cs
[Test]
public void FilterSomething_Test()
{
    List<MyClass> testdata = new List<MyClass>
    {
        new MyClass { SomeProperty = "expectedValue" },
        new MyClass { SomeProperty = "expectedValue" },
        new MyClass { SomeProperty = "unexpectedValue" },
        new MyClass { SomeProperty = "unexpectedValue" },
        new MyClass { SomeProperty = null },
    }

    List<MyClass> result = FilterSomething(testdata);

    Assert.That(
        result.Where(r => r.SomeProperty == "expectedValue"),
        Has.Exactly(2).Items,
        "Two Items should match this..");
}
```

Output for failed test:

> Two Items should match this..
>
> Expected: exactly 2 items
>
> But was:  no items

The output doesn't explain what went wrong.

**Explanation:** I've got a testdata for multiple tests. This is why I want to check for specific items in each test.

**My question:**

Is there a way to check for item-counts in a list and get a *proper message* from `NUnit`?

Perhaps something like

```
Assert.That(result, Contains.Exacly(2).Items.Which(i => i.SomeProperty == "expectedValue"))
```

Comment: I'd say it is an opinion based question, and could maybe go to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead (but with the real code). Also I'd say it is fine the way it is, maybe you could pull `result.Where(r => r.SomeProperty == "expectedVale")` into a own variable so that the `Assert.That` is better to read which is the whole point of this format.

Comment: Another comment before somebody points out my falacy: `Assert.That` is not only used because it's easy to read. It also allows for custom constraints which in some cases is convenient.

Comment: @FeRaaC It's not opinion-based. `result.Where(...)` prevents NUnit to understand what you want to do. I will only tell you that "some collection" should have more or less items. @Chris wrote a good answer: I can check `Properties` instead of using a `Where()`.

Comment: @kara concerns about it being opinion-based could be assuaged if you clarify what you mean by "better". It sounds like you have some specific, objective criteria from your comment; can you add that to the question?

Comment: @TylerH ok, you're right.. :) "better" suspects a bad question. The goal was to get a meaningful message from NUnit for the Assertion. I modified the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is `Matches` constraint expression dedicated for that.
Usage in this case could look like:

```
Assert.That(result, 
    Has.Exactly(2).Matches<MyClass>(r => r.SomeProperty == "expectedValue"),
    "Two Items should match this..");
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, absolutely! NUnit constraints can be chained together, to allow you to be really quite perscriptive in terms of your actual assertion. The advantage of this is that you'll get a more precise error message when your test fails - so in my opinion, it's good practice to include as much logic as possible within the actual NUnit assertion.

In this case, I believe you could write something like this:

```
Assert.That(result,
 Contains.Exactly(2).Items.Property(nameof(MyClass.ExpectedProperty)).EqualTo("expectedValue");
```

Comment: Thanks. `.Property(nameof(MyClass.ExpectedProperty))` is what I was searching for!